# Facebook authentication via AWS Cognito

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, facebook-authentication

I have an AWS Cognito User Pool set to federate authentication to Facebook and Google. It works fine with Google, not with Facebook.

[image: Authentication screen]

When I click on "Continue with Facebook", the URL changes to "https://m.facebook.com" and the pages displays "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

I find that puzzling because I believe I've properly configured the settings this error references.

Here's my app settings in facebook's developer console, the app domain is set. It has the format `<domain prefix>.auth.<aws region>.amazoncognito.com` to match the hosted UI of the AWS Cognito User Pool.

[image]

Here's my app's OAUTH settings in facebook's developer console. Note the URLs are the app domain prefixed with `https://` and in one of the two URLs it's appended with `oauth2/idresponse` just in case, since Cognito seems to append that at least when it federates to Google.

[image]

This facebook app also has a website set in the FB developer console as follows:

[image]

I've followed AWS documentation for federating a Cognito User Pool to Facebook available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-federation-with-social-idp.html)

The facebook app status is "Off: In Development". I assume that is acceptable, the app is not ready to be publicly available yet I need to be able to test authentication.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-federation-with-social-idp.html. You should add Site URL as https://{your-user-pool-domain}/oauth2/idpresponse

Step 9: Under Website, type your user pool domain with the /oauth2/idpresponse endpoint into Site URL.

```
https://<your-user-pool-domain>/oauth2/idpresponse
```